# Promises break while building a pages

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using promise and `http.get` to fetch data from JSON API from Wordpress

After fetching the data, I will show the data on a page..

But the error show because the data is not available while building the page

How to solve that error ?

Here's my service code

```
loadPost(id) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('http://blog.macg.xyz/api/get_post/?id='+id)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(post => {
                this.post = post;
                resolve(this.post);
                console.log(this.post);
            });
        });
    }
```

And here's the controller

```
export class PostPage {
    public id:any;
    public post: any;
    public loading : any;

  constructor(public postService: PostService, public navCtrl: NavController,  params: NavParams, public loadCtrl: LoadingController) {
    this.id = params.get("id");
    // this.onPageWillEnter();
  }

  onPageWillEnter() {
    // Starts the process 
    this.showLoading();
  }

  showLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadCtrl.create({
      content: "Please wait..."
    });
    // Show the loading page
    this.loading.present();
    // Get the Async information 
    this.loadPost();
  }

  loadPost(){
      this.postService.loadPost(this.id) // here where I call the service
      .then(data => {
        this.post = data;
        console.log(this.post);
        this.hideLoading();
      });
    }

    hideLoading(){
    // Hide the loading component
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Here's the html code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{id}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
    {{post.post.content}}
</ion-content>
```

And here's the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is thrown from your template file, maybe post.post.content is throwing the error. If your post is null (which is true at first run), trying to reach its post variable may throw that error.

You can control whether the post is null or not, such as

```
<ion-content padding ng-if="post">
     {{post.post.content}}
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I just realize, my `post` empty when I'm entered the page.. Even when I'm `console.log(this.post)` in my controller still show the value.. How can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *elvis operator* **?** to avoid that error from being thrown when the `post` property is still null

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{id}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
    {{post?.post.content}}
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Still got the error.. I just realize, `{{post}}` in the HTML is empty, therefore, `this.post` on the controller have a value.. I think the HTML rendered before promises finish... How to make the promise finish first then build the page ?

Comment: The html will be rendered before the promise finish (that's the expected behaviour). As soon as the promise finishes, the value of the `post` will be updated and thanks to _zones_ the html will be updated too. So the error must be somewhere else...

Comment: I don't now where I need to guess the error is.. But I only have a clue that when I'm not using `{{post}}` on my HTML, the code on controller works fine and `this.post` have their value (checked by `console.log`)... But when I'm using the `{{post}}` on the HTML, It breaks all my code, even the `console.log(this.post)` on `loadPost` function in controller

Comment: I read a bit the last line of the error, It says `ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object] ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ` Why there's no value ?? Is my navParams late and I get notihing from the service ?

Comment: Hmmm... add a `debugger` as the first line of code of the `loadPost` method  from the service (not the one in the Component) and check if the id is correct. Also please paste what `data` is when you do `this.post = data;`

Comment: You mean I need to `console.log(id)` on my service and `console.log(data)` on my controller ?

Comment: I meant [debugger;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) but yes, a `console.log(...)` can be used too.. this is just to be sure that you're making the http call properly...